# Insert from another table and also insert new value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, one of them is 'user_flag' and the other is 'playlist_data'.

I want to take all 'object_id' column entries of 'user_flag' and place them into the respective 'object_id' column of 'playlist_data', but only if those entries have '3' as the 'user' entry, and that they do not already exist (no duplicate 'object_id's!).

I tried to learn how to do it and this is what I found:

```
INSERT INTO playlist_data (object_id)
SELECT object_id FROM user_flag
WHERE user='3';
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE object_id=object_id
```

Will this work properly?

But I'm also trying to do more at the same time, and I can't seem to find an answer:

1) I want to also insert new data with this. I want all of the newly inserted entries to also contain '5' in the 'filetype' column of 'playlist_data'.

Do I just

```
INSERT INTO playlist_data (filtype)
VALUES (5)
```

in the middle of all of this?

2) Both tables also have an 'id' column, will it automatically generate a new id followed from the latest 'id' of 'playlist_data'?

As in for example, I'm transferring from 'user_flag' an entry with the 'id' of '150', while the highest 'id' in 'playlist_data' is '63', will the inserted one by '64', or do I need to define that somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the value in the `SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO playlist_data (object_id, filtype)
    SELECT object_id, 5
    FROM user_flag
    WHERE user = 3
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE object_id = VALUES(object_id);
```

Notes:

- I am guessing that the id columns are numbers.  Hence, I removed the single quotes.
- I use `VALUES(object_id)` in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.
- It is important to have the semicolon only at the very end of the statement.

Comment: Well that explains why it didn't work, I didn't placed the semicolon correctly. I'm starting to understand now, it's all one sentence, just split into multiple rows for better layout. However, I forgot to note that 'user_flag' doesn't have a 'filetype' column, I just want to insert completely new value, not transfer it from 'user_flag', will it still work?

Comment: @Potatoman Read the `SELECT` query by itself, you'll see that it's not trying to access `filtype` from `user_flag`. It's just selecting a literal `5` in that column.

Comment: You probably also need to add `filtype = VALUES(filtype)` in the `DUPLICATE KEY` clause.